# How to upload a file attachment in HTML5/DHTML mode of OpenLaszlo 4.9.0+

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

How do you upload a file attachment using the DHTML/HTML5 run-time of OpenLaszlo 4.9.0/5.0.x?

I know that it is not officially supported by OpenLaszlo but I know that at least two people have done it in proprietary code that they are not allowed to share, but maybe somebody else out there has done it in shareable code.

Comment: Take an HTML5 file upload example, and make an OpenLaszlo component out of it. You have to write your own upload routine, using XMLHttpRequest and FormData. If you want to preview images, use the FileReader API and draw the image into a HTML5 canvas or OpenLaszlo drawview.

Comment: [This code](http://www.weeby.pl/blog/html5uploader/html5uploader.js) should get you started. Or check [this example](http://css.dzone.com/articles/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple).

Comment: Thanks Raju, I'll look at this later this week.

Comment: I'd have a bit of time to work on a component with you, if you are still interested. I sent a message to the boston(at)oldev.org mailing list.